# Trouble understanding meaning of functional dependency notation (A - > BC)

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I'm having a hard time visualizing exactly what A->BC means, mainly what exactly BC does.
For example, on a table "If A -> B and B -> C, then A -> C" would look like this, and the statement would be true:

```
A  |  B  |  C 
1  |  2  |  3 
1  |  2  |  3
```

What would A -> BC look like?

How would you show something like "If AB -> C, then A -> BC" is false?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
My guess at it is that AB -> C means that C is dependant on both A and B, so the table would look like this:

```
A  |  B  |  C 
1  |  2  |  3 
1  |  2  |  3
```

Or this (which would be a counterexample for my question above):

```
A  |  B  |  C 
1  |  2  |  4 
1  |  3  |  4
```

And both would be true. But this would be false:

```
A  |  B  |  C 
1  |  2  |  4 
1  |  3  |  5
```

Is that the right idea?

Comment: For both of your last two examples, `AB -> C` is true and `A -> BC` is false.  The change to the second value in the C column doesn't make a difference w.r.t. these potential functional dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you haven't already read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency), it's an okay introduction to functional dependencies.  It says:

> Union: If X → Y and X → Z, then X → YZ
>
> Decomposition: If X → YZ, then X → Y and X → Z

I find it helpful to read `A -> B` as "A determines B", and read `A -> BC` as "A determines B and C".  In other words, given an A, you can uniquely determine the value of B and C, but it's not necessarily true that given a B and a C, you can uniquely determine the value of A.

Here's a simple example:  a table with at least 3 columns, where A is the primary key and B and C are any other columns:

```
 id | x | y
------------
 1  | 7 | 4
 2  | 9 | 4
 3  | 7 | 6
```

To show that `If AB -> C, then A -> BC` is false, you just have to come up with a single counter-example.  Here's one:  a table where AB is the primary key (therefore by definition it satisfies `AB -> C`):

```
 A | B | C
------------
 1 | 1 | 4
 1 | 2 | 5
 2 | 1 | 6
 2 | 2 | 4
```

However, it does not satisfy `A -> B` (because for A=1, B=1,2) and therefore, by Union, it does not satisfy `A -> BC`.  (Bonus points: does it satisfy `A -> C`?  Does it matter?)